# Nokogiri response of empty node cache when run within application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I have created a class within an application:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

    class Scraper
        def self.test_method
            url = "http://london.craigslist.co.uk/"
            doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
            Rails.logger.debug doc.to_yaml
        end
    end
```

When calling this within a rails console: `Scraper.test_method` I get an empty node cache. However if I run those individual lines of the method directly in the console the response is a valid `Nokogiri::HTML::Document` object with complete node cache.

What is different between the console and the application?

```
--- !ruby/object:Nokogiri::HTML::Document
decorators:
node_cache: []
errors:
- !ruby/exception:Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError
  message: |
    Tag article invalid
  domain: 5
  code: 801
  level: 2
  file: /var/folders/lt/18lgdxts4052x8rf8xhf32v00000gn/T/open-uri20131218-62789-1tuxgqp
  line: 50
  str1: article
  str2:
  str3:
  int1: 0
  column: 28
- !ruby/exception:Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError
  message: |
    Tag section invalid
  domain: 5
  code: 801
  level: 2
  file: /var/folders/lt/18lgdxts4052x8rf8xhf32v00000gn/T/open-uri20131218-62789-1tuxgqp
  line: 51
  str1: section
  str2:
  str3:
  int1: 0
  column: 23
- !ruby/exception:Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError
  message: |
    Tag header invalid
  domain: 5
  code: 801
  level: 2
  file: /var/folders/lt/18lgdxts4052x8rf8xhf32v00000gn/T/open-uri20131218-62789-1tuxgqp
  line: 161
  str1: header
  str2:
  str3:
  int1: 0
  column: 36
- !ruby/exception:Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError
  message: |
    Tag footer invalid
  domain: 5
  code: 801
  level: 2
  file: /var/folders/lt/18lgdxts4052x8rf8xhf32v00000gn/T/open-uri20131218-62789-1tuxgqp
  line: 678
  str1: footer
  str2:
  str3:
  int1: 0
  column: 9
```

Comment: Is that the entire Yaml document you get, or have you just included the errors?

Comment: I've updated the question... that is exactly what I get back. Whereas when running individual lines in the console the node cache is complete with object:Nokogiri::XML objects within the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line in your `Scraper#test_method` is the `Rails.logger` line, which is returning nil, causing your method to return nil.  You'll need to use `return doc` (or just `doc`) at the end of your method so it returns that result.